# How can I change the colour of button in my fragment from my adapter?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a fragment, `ButtonSharingFragment`, whose layout is called `sharing_buttons.xml`, it consists of 3 buttons.

I embed it in my `NewContact` activity with, in the `layout` of `NewContact`:

```
 <fragment
     android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.ButtonSharingFragment"
     android:id = "@+id/myFragment"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

My App loads up fine, I see the fragment where it is supposed to be. But I am trying to change the colour of one of the buttons in the fragment, when all checkboxes in my `recyclerView` are unchecked. The `recyclerView` is in my activity, `NewContact`. Can you tell me how to do this?

Here is my `ButtonSharingFragment` code:

```
public class ButtonSharingFragment extends Fragment{

    Button phoneContacts;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment

        View buttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);

        phoneContacts = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.btnPhoneContacts);

        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        return buttonView;
    }

}
```

And the `OnBindViewHolder` of my `adapter`, when a checkbox is clicked. What goes into `if(count==0) { }` ?

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


            //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
            final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);


                //in the title textbox in the row, put the corresponding name etc...
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).getSelected());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);

                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                        Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();


                        //NEED THIS TO PRESERVE CHECKBOX STATE
                        if (theContactsList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);


                        } else {


                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);



                        }


                        //we want to keep track of checked boxes, so when it is '0'
                        //'Phone Contacts' button in ButtonSharingFragment will change 

                //HOW TO DO THIS?

                        int count;
                        count = 0;
                        int size = theContactsList.size();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            if (theContactsList.get(i).isSelected) {
                                count++;


                            }
                        }
                        Log.i("MyMessage","The count is " + count);


                        //if 'count' is 0, then change button colour in ButtonSharingFragment fragment

                        if (count==0){

                //CHANGE COLOUR OF phoneContacts button in ButtonSharingFragment
    //have tried interface/callback etc, must be doing it wrong

                        }

                    }

                });

            }
```

**EDIT: Modified my code to look like below, but am getting NullPointerException.**

I have created a java class called `UpdateColorCallback` :

```
public interface UpdateColorCallback {
    void onUpdateColorCallback();
}
```

In my adapter I have included:

```
public class PopulistoContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder > {


    private UpdateColorCallback updateColorCallback;


    public void setUpdateLisenter(UpdateColorCallback updateColorCallback) {
        this.updateColorCallback = updateColorCallback;
    }
```

And in my `ButtonSharingFragment`:

```
public class ButtonSharingFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateColorCallback {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Button publicContacts;
    Button phoneContacts;
    Button justMeContacts;

    // ArrayList called selectPhoneContacts that will contain SelectPhoneContact info
    ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts;

    // The onCreateView method is called when Fragment should create its View object hierarchy,
    // either dynamically or via XML layout inflation.
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter = new PopulistoContactsAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, getActivity());

         adapter.setUpdateListener(this);

        View buttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);


        //for the Public, phoneContacts, justMe, save and cancel buttons
        publicContacts = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.btnPublic);
        phoneContacts = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.btnPhoneContacts);
        justMeContacts = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.btnJustMe);



        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        return buttonView;
    }




    @Override
    public void onUpdateColorCallback() {
        // TODO: Implement this
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "yes, this is working now"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("MyMessage","yes, this is working now");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to make interface first then pass reference from fragment to adapter. Now when you want to change color or when you match your condition then you need to call.

Make Interface :-

```
public interface UpdateColorCallback {
    void onUpdateColorCallback();
}
```

Now you need to implement into your fragment

```
public class ButtonSharingFragment extends Fragment implement UpdateColorCallback{

    Button phoneContacts;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment

        View buttonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharing_buttons, parent, false);


        // pass this from here to adapter
        adapter.setUpdateLisenter(this);

        phoneContacts = (Button) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.btnPhoneContacts);



        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        return buttonView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdateColorCallback() {
         //change button color
    }


}
```

Adapter code:-

```
private UpdateColorCallback updateColorCallback;
public void setUpdateLisenter(UpdateColorCallback updateColorCallback) {
     this.updateColorCallback = updateColorCallback;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    // when ur condition meet then 
    if(updateColorCallback != null) {
        // this call back call fragment 
        updateColorCallback. onUpdateColorCallback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to implement your code, having a few problems. UpdateAlertCallback, what is this referring to?

Comment: this is just a typo mistake so you have to use UpdateColorCallback instead of UpdateAlertCallback

Comment: just a typo - I thought so and changed it and all loads correctly, all variables recognised. But callback is not going to the fragment (button not changing colour). When I remove `if(updateColorCallback != null)` I get `NullPointerException` on line `updateColorCallback.onUpdateColorCallback();`In my Fragment I did add `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, getActivity());` so `adapter.setUpdateLisenter(this);` would know what I was talking about.Any ideas?

Comment: still you are missing to pass reference from fragment to adapter ( adapter.setUpdateLisenter(this);)

Comment: I have `adapter.setUpdateLisenter(this);` in my `ButtonSharingFragment` as you describe above, is that not right? What more do I need to do?

Comment: dnt mind can i show your code in pastebin or any other where you want to show?

Comment: I added the code to my question, after the 'EDIT'. This ok? Could try Pastebin if it helps more, tx.

Comment: on your ButtonSharingFragment .java change adapter. setUpdateLisenter(this);  instead of  adapter.setPlayPauseClickListener(this);

Comment: I am sorry that is a typo when I was editing/pasting, it is in fact already adapter. setUpdateLisenter(this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164749/discussion-between-duggu-and-charris).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Button instance to your adapter class from fragment and change the button state in the adapter,like:

```
adapter =new ButtonAdapter(button);
```

then in the adapter :

```
    Button button1;

       ButtonAdapter(Button button)
            {
              button1=button;
            }

            if (count==0){        
   button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white,null));
            }
```